# Convert route parameter to nullable number

Tags: angular, typescript

On an Angular 12 application I have the following class:

```
export class UserModel {
  id?: number;
  email: string;
}
```

On a component I need to get the id and email from the route so I have:

```
  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      (value: ParamMap) => { 
        this.user = { 
          id: value.has('id') ? value?.get('id') : undefined,
          email: value.has('email') ? value?.get('email') : undefined
        }
      });
      
  }
```

But I get an error on `id`:

```
Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
```

I also tried:

```
id: value.has('userId') ? +(value?.get('userId')) : undefined,
```

but got:

```
Object is possibly 'null'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe you could use the  [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to return the value or `undefined`.  Like this:  `id: value.get('id') ?? undefined`

Comment: @BizzyBob Your suggestion does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `!` operator, like this:

```js
this.user = { 
  id: value.has('id') ? value!.get('id') : undefined,
  email: value.has('email') ? value!.get('email') : undefined
}
```